# Is a rolling $z$-score a good proxy for a derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, discrete-mathematics, time-series

Given a time series $\{V_t\}_{t=1}^{n}$, where $t \mapsto V_t \in \mathbb{R}$, I want to have some smoothed notion of the "derivative" of this time series. It was recommended that I look at

$$\tilde{V}_t = \frac{V_t - \text{$k$-step moving average of } V_t}{\text{$k$-step std dev of $V_t$}}.$$

The $k$-step moving average of $V_t$ is $\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}V_{t-i}$.

This quantity, empirically, seems to act something like derivative. (For a line it is constant, for a sine curve it is almost a cosine curve, etc.) Can someone explain why, mathematically, this would be a heuristic for a derivative?

Thanks.

Comment: Derivatives don't really make sense with discrete time, so it's better to compare it to the differences $V_t - V_{t-1}$.  In both cases you're looking at measures of how quickly $V_t$ is changing relative to the recent past, so you would expect the metrics to have similar properties.

Comment: @JairTaylor Derivatives do have a discrete analogue, [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).

Comment: @Théophile Sure, you could also compare to finite difference quotients over longer intervals.